# Parsing id to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

When parsing API responses, sometimes I can not rely on strings being embedded in quotation marks. ID's are a good example of this, where some API's will send the numerical ID as a string while some will send it as a number.

What is a good practice when parsing such a value? If I simply parse it to an `NSString` like so:

```
NSString *myID = (NSString *)message["myID"];
```

I can end up with an `NSString` object that somehow contains `(long)123`.

And using `stringValue` would cause issues when the value is actually already sent as a string (since `NSString` does not have a `stringValue` function).

A way that works, but is somewhat ugly, is this:

```
id myID = (NSString *)message["myID"];
if ([myID respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)])
{
    myID = [myID stringValue];
}
```

Comment: The response is protocol. It should be always same or there must be very specific reason in server side. @superx3man's answer seems easy solution but you better talk to server side before you do this.

Comment: You can't store a `long` in a dictionary. Of course it could be an `NSNumber` representing a `long`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
id myID = message["myID"];
if ([myID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { ... }
else { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as this logic is encapsulated inside data parser and is opaque for your api users (i.e. they will always get a string) any approach is fine, e.g.:

```
- (NSString*)parseID:(NSDictionary*)message {
   id rawID = message["myID"];
   if ([rawID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
     return rawID;
   } else if ([rawID isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
     return [(NSNumber*)rawID stringValue];
   } else {
      // We might still want to handle this case.
      NSAssert(false, @"Unexpected id type");
      return nil;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to define stringValue in extension, so any possible objet will respond to selector:

```
@implementation NSString(JSONStringParsing)
- (NSString *)stringValue {
    return [self copy];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `description`?

```
NSArray *objects = @[
        @NSIntegerMin,
        @NSIntegerMax,
        @"123456789"
        ];
for (id object in objects) {
    NSString *stringObject = [object description];
    NSLog(@"%@ -> %@ | %@", [object className], [stringObject className], stringObject);
}
```